# Server hangs at "Shutting down loopback interface" on reboot

Tags: centos, iscsi, server-crashes, loopback, kernel-panic

I'm having some trouble understanding what's going on with connecting one of our Xen hypervisors to our iSCSI SAN.

Ever since we mounted our iSCSI targets, we've experienced hanging on reboots.

This is what it looks like...

```
 Stopping iscsi:                           [ OK ]
 Shutting down system logger:              [ OK ]
 Stopping iscsid:                          [ OK ]
 Shutting down interface eth0:             [ OK ]
 Shutting down interface eth1:             [ OK ]
 Shutting down loopback interface:         [ OK ]
```

Then it hangs there.  We have to perform a power cycle to get it to come back online.

We are running CentOS 6.4 with Xen 4

```
[root@hypervisor1 ~]# uname -a
Linux hypervisor1.localhost 3.4.59-8.el6.centos.alt.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 22 20:19:06 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

These were the commands that were run - we think its probably the last one thats the culprit..

```
iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p 10.100.1.2
iscsiadm -m node -l -T iqn.2011-12:san1.target0
iscsiadm -m node -T iscsiadm -m session
iscsiadm -m session
iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2011-12:san1.target0 -p 10.100.1.2 -o update -n node.startup -v automatic
```

Answer (score 1):

Applied patch at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=583218 which resolved the issue.